# htaccess - Remove trailing period

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do I remove the trailing period (dot) with htaccess?

If a visitor goes to http://example.com/mypage. it'll give a 404 error.  I already have the following in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://example/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ http://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I assumed adding this would work, but it doesn't:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.$ http://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you will need to do some debugging using [mod_rewrite’s logging feature](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel).

Comment: I have the same problem.  The rewriterule: [pre] RewriteRule ^author/([A-z.]+)/([A-z]+)$ 
get_author_articles.php?first_name=$1&last_name=$2 applied to http://localhost:8080/API/author/J./Doe

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

will remove a trailing dot

Comment: This is basically the same regex that Eliza said wouldn't work.  (You have a `+` rather than `*`, otherwise it's identical.)  Is there some subtlety here?  If so, you should probably mention it.